# react native call action from provider App.js

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I use react native and redux as following (working):

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ...store.getState()};
    store.subscribe(() => {
      // i can read the state but no write it
      const storestate = store.getState();       
    });
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    this.setState({ isConnected });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate
          loading={<ActivityIndicator />}
          persistor={persistor}>

          <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: Config.marginTop }}>
            <StackView />

          </View>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

---

ScreenX.js

```
import * as actions from "./redux/actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class ScreenX extends React.Component {
    ...
    // i can do in any fonction 
    this.props.action_saveNetInfo(isConnected);
    ...
}

function mapToStateProps(data) {
  return {
    isConnected: data["isConnected"] 
  };
}
export default connect(mapToStateProps, actions)(ScreenX);
```

The redux store work nice when i call actions from other component than App.js

**Problem :**

I want to call action from APP.js but this don't work

```
  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    this.props.action_saveNetInfo(isConnected);
  };
```

error : `TypeError: this.props.action_saveNetInfo is not a function`

I cannot do this too

```
  class App extends React.PureComponent { ...   }

  export default connect(null, null)(App)
```

because it throw an error :

```
    Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".
```

Any idea ? 
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within App component, you can call the `dispatch` directly from the `store`. Then, you just need to dispatch your actionCreator.

```
import {action_saveNetInfo} from './redux/actions'
// ...
handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    store.dispatch(action_saveNetInfo(isConnected));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mapDispatchToProps function to binding actions to this.props

Comment: `export default connect(null, null)(App)` throw an error . the second parameters of connect is mapDispatchToProps  or action. i use action

Comment: `mapDispatchToProps = dıspatch => {
//return some actions;
}
export default connect(mapToStateProps, mapDispatchToProps )(Something)`
use like this.
Examples with mapDispatchToProps => https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: Thx, this is what is use usually ( action = mapdispatch) . if i use connect in App ( whatever param i give ) it throws error

Comment: please look at Diogo Sgrillo response, it work. your work from other components than App. sagol